# How to convert VMDK file to fixed VHD

Tags: vhd

Now I am going to convert VMDK to VHD .but I won't know how to convert this file and, I already tried using winimage and HyperV but,
I need this VHD file for Azure Template Deployment and as per Azure recommendation azure only need Fixed VHD.
Any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: VMDK IS VMWare VHD is the legacy Microsoft virtual disk file format.  You want to covert to VHDX not VHD

Answer (score 1):

Try out starwind v2v converter:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter

It supports practically all well known formats, performs fast and, as the saying goes, it just works.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into a tool called `qemu-img`.  It's sole purpose is converting between virtual hard disk image formats.  It's command-line only, but it is reasonably fast, and very memory efficient.  Documentation can be found [here](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#qemu_005fimg_005finvocation).